# How to implement a neural network to play an endless runner game?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

After learning the basics of neural networks I want to create a small but an unique project (something more difficult than handwritten digits etc). 
I chose to implement an endless runner game, record my moves and train a neural network with the collected data.

**Game looks like this:**

[image]

Player can move to right and to left (arrows) , the goal is to avoid asteroids. 
When player presses left arrow, coordinates of all asteroids, player position and left move are recorded.
When player presses right arrow, the same thing happens but "move" is set to right. 
I had a problem with figuring out how to record no movement so I coded it to record no movement (straight) when i press up arrow. So when I wasn't moving, i was pressing up arrow (at a medium pace)

There can be maximum of 20 asteroids but I collected data for a smaller data set, to see how it works.

**Collected data looks like this:**

[image]

As you can see in the first row, there are 42 columns.
20 columns for x-coordinates of all asteroids on the board.
20 columns for y-coordinates of all asteroids on the board. 
1 column for x-coordinate of a player
1 column for a move (0 - left; 1 - right; 2 - straight, no movement)

I collected 4042 samples:
1140 left
1122 right
1780 straight

As I said before, I prepared it to handle 20 asteroids but I collected data for a only of few of them so the rest of the columns are filled with zeros.

**I used tensorflow to train a neural network**

```
data = pd.read_csv('collected_data.csv')
y = data['move']
x = data.drop('move', axis=1)
x_train = x.to_numpy()
y_train = y.to_numpy()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41,activation='hard_sigmoid',input_shape=x_train[0].shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='hard_sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='hard_sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='hard_sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

model.save('model.h5')
```

**Result:**

[image]

My model doesn't fit at all. When i run the game, spaceship is not moving at all, always chosing to go straight. I tried different neural network architectures, more layers, fewer layers etc. but it almost doesn't change the result. Do I have not enough data ? Data is too complex? Did I choose the wrong model? 
I will be grateful for any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bartosz, I would recommend looking at reinforcement learning for a problem such as this. Reinforcement learning is good at learning games where there is a set of objectives leading towards a successful (surviving) or unsuccessful (crashing) game. See https://gym.openai.com/\

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. The thing is that I know reinforcment learning is usually used for such things,  I wanted to do the same thing with supervised learning. Is it possible ?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but the way you are doing it probably not. I think you'd need to generate some probabilistic output which can be sampled from (like reinforcement learning) otherwise your model will always do the same thing (which might not be a bad thing). Other that that you might want to track history so you can see what the previous N moves were or something. Another thing is you should remove your last layer's activation function as you've specified that the loss function is "from_logits".

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to do this with reinforcment learning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you. I will try to do this with reinforcment learning.